# SQL to show min,max during timerange where name =(x)

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to establish a basic report function.

The tables contain basic columns like this

ID, timestamp, value, key, Query, JSON

The only unique identifier is in the key colum

Theres half a million rows

I'd like it to report back this basically

```
SELECT min(value) as begin, max(value) as end FROM `key`WHERE NAME='Key1'
TIMERANGE='LastMonth'
```

Could someone please assist with the syntax of this or the concepts im missing
Thankyou and much appreciated

Comment: You are missing the concept of `AND`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT min(value) as begin, max(value) as end FROM `key`
WHERE NAME='Key1' and 
timestamp>=date_add(current_date(),interval -1 month) and timestamp<=current_date()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(value) as begin, max(value) as end FROM `key` 
WHERE ID='Key1'
AND timestamp >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0)
AND timestamp <= DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

OR

```
SELECT ID, min(value) as begin, max(value) as end FROM `key`
WHERE timestamp >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0)
AND timestamp <= DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
GROUP BY ID
```